# Is the coincidence between these large numbers purely accidental?

Tags: measurements

Following are 3 sets of some very interesting data:

Size of proton- $10^{-15}$m

Size of observable universe- $10^{26}$ m

Mass of an electron- $10^{-30}$ kg

Mass of observable universe- $10^{55}$kg

Life span of the most unstable particle- $10^{-24}$s

Age of the universe- $10^{17}$s

As you can see, by comparing the extreme values of mass, length and time present in the observable universe. We get the approximate ratio of the two extreme cases as the following:

Mass- $(10^{41})^2$

Length- $10^{41}$

Time- $10^{41}$

Is the coincidence between these large numbers which represents fundamental physical quantities of the universe,purely accidental?

Comment: Sounds like [Dirac large numbers hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis)

Comment: Hmm....thanks for the link....got a lot of info on this interesting hypothesis....I think it will remain a 'hypothesis'....seems to be too much of a coincidence...

Comment: The argument vs Diracs hypothesis has been that there's lots of numbers around, you can always find some relations.  The other one is that it's been around for about 80 years and nobody has proven anything from those

Comment: [It should be $10^{42}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), the universe is larger, and the most unstable particle decays faster.